# Javascript, simplifying object transformation

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

So I have a function that takes an object and turns it into a (slightly) different one.  I did a first take of it to just get it working, and now I would like to simplify this function, I feel like I could cut down a bit but could use some help doing it.

So the object gets passed in like so

```
 {"module1":{"calender":["yes","no","maybe"]}}
```

and gets spit out like so

```
 {module1: "calender,yes,no,maybe"}
```

So here is what I have now :

```
 function(obj) {

                for (i in obj) {

                    for (p in obj[i]) {
                        var decodeModule = encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(i));
                        var newObj = {};
                        var frontOf = encodeURIComponent(p);
                        var backOf = ""
                            //needs work
                        var lastItem = obj[i][p][obj[i][p].length - 1];
                        for (y in obj[i][p]) {

                            if (obj[i][p][y] == lastItem) {
                                //replace "," in last item
                                backOf += encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(obj[i][p][y]));
                            } else {
                                backOf += encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(obj[i][p][y])) + ",";
                            }
                        };
                        newObj[decodeModule] = frontOf + "," + backOf;
                    }
                }
                return newObj;
            }
```

So I already know that I don't need to loop the second loop ( for (p in obj[i]) ) because that level will always only have 1 item. Other than that I am a bit stuck on how to clean this bit up - it was suggested to me to maybe check out .reduce or .map to use less code? I am also using underscore in my code, if it would help here.  Would LOVE it if someone could help me make this a bit more elegant. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this was an interesting exercise. After I completed it I was like "Why are we doing this again?" :)

I reduce the property value to a string and then did a replace using a regex and _.map to replace each match. 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYgodo

I know this as well can be improved. Someone tear it apart please!!

```
var input = {
"module1": {
"calender": ["yes", "no", "maybe"]
},
"module2": {
"falender": ["yes", "no", "jein"]
}
};

//output: {module1: "calender,yes,no,maybe"}

function reduceObj(obj) {
newObj = {};


_.each(obj, function (value, key, list) {

var r = new RegExp(/(?:^({).*(:\[).*(\]})$)/);
//reduce property value to string and replace using regex
newObj[key] = JSON.stringify(list[key]).replace(r, function (match, p1, p2,    p3, p4, p5, offset, string) {
//this may be the only way to replace each capture
_.map([p1, p2, p3, p4], function (value, index, list) {
match = match.replace(value, "");
}); //end map

//replace double quote with comma and single quote with nothing
return match.replace(/\"\"/g, ',').replace(/\"/g, "");

}); //end replace


}); //end each

return newObj;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
console.log(reduceObj(input));
$('#output').html(JSON.stringify(reduceObj(input)));

});
```

Comment: Any way to tack the encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent parts in this method?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify on that - the key name and items inside that final object need to be put through an encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(stuff here)) , I am not sure how to stick that into your method, I tried for a bit. ( I am pulling them out of a url query string and putting them back in so I need the decode/re-encode)

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you show me what the final URL would look like? Are you trying to achieve this?:  www.website.com/?calender=yes,no,maybe

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? No underscore, no regex, just good old vanilla JavaScript.

```js
var input = {
  1: {
    "calender": ["yes", "no", "maybe"]
  },
  "module2": {
    "test2": ["|", "#", "&", "?", ",", "+", " ", "\\", "\""]
  },
  "One More for Good Measure": {}
};

function reduceObj(obj) {
  function helper(o) {
    var key = Object.keys(o)[0];
    if (typeof key != 'string') return '';
    return [].concat(key, o[key]).map(e_d).join(',');
  }

  function e_d(str) {
    return encodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(str));
  }
  
  var newObj = {}, prop;

  for (prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      newObj[e_d(prop)] = helper(obj[prop]);
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}

var output = reduceObj(input);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(output, 0, 2));
```

If you have multiple keys under `module2` (for example) all you need to do is change `helper`: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5xexcsaz/6/)

```
function helper(o) {
  var arr = [];   
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key) {
      o[key].unshift(key);
      arr = arr.concat(o[key]);
  });
  return arr.map(e_d).join(',');
}
```

Comment: This is also fantastic! Thanks for the help. Can I stick the encode/decode parts in here?

Comment: @Alex, I am pretty sure you can, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @Alex, I am not entirely sure what you are using encode/decode for, it would help me out if you explained why you are using the functions.

Comment: They are being encoded because they are being put on a url string. The reason for the encode(decode(item) is because that item may have been pulled off a url string (also might have not) so it decodes first before it encodes as to not double encode it.

Comment: So it encode(decodes() the module name itself, then the items inside it before pushing it into the final newObj

Comment: @Alex, okay I have added the encode/decode stuff to the answer, you can see the effect in the in `input.module2.test2`